# Is it possible to handle trigger error in Power Automate or Logic App?

Tags: error-handling, triggers, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

Using "Configure run after" to handle errors thrown by flow **action** is [a well-known pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/error-handling/2-configure-run-after).

But what about a **trigger** that has failed? Is there a way to configure the flow to, say, send a message, when an error occurs in a trigger?

For example, my flow is triggered when an item is created or modified on a SharePoint list and if someone deletes this list I will never know that something is wrong until I browse the flow trigger history and see "list not found" trigger error.  However, it won't even appear in runs history because the flow won't start any action, so I guess "Configure run after" is useless in such case? Any other options?

Comment: A rejected edit suggestion of your is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/429576/3404097).

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use flow management connectors (these will monitor errors)
2. you can enable flow failure emails
3. you can implement error handling in a secondary flow (this would be a separate flow that will monitor the health of your sharepoint list)

Comment: Are you sure any of these are applicable to **trigger** errors? Any examples would be appreciated.